# VPN: access subnet of client

Tags: vpn

i have VPN setup which is like this:

```
########### internet  ############## internet  ############   LAN   ############
# macbook # --------> # VPN server #----------># PC A     # -------># PC B     #
#10.8.0.6 #           # 10.8.0.1   #           # 10.8.0.7 #         # 192.168..#
###########           ##############           ############         ############
```

and now i want to access the PC B in the local LAN of PC A ( A is in VPN net ) with my macbook, I can access PC A with my macbook, so VPN works, i just need some way to route the traffic from the macbook over PC A ( i guess ) to reach PC B in the LAN of PC A, i cant add PC B to the vpn net because i dont have (physical) access to it. ( i hope this is not too confusing ) how can i do this? VPN Server and PC A are running Debian,

any advice is greatly appreciated :), and sorry for my bad english

Comment: [Please don't](http://unix.stackexchange.com/faq#cross-posting) [cross-post](http://superuser.com/questions/451806/connect-to-subnet-via-vpn).

Comment: Still open on SU; closing here

Answer (score 1):

If it were Linux, the command you'd use would be:

```
ip route add 192.168.0.0/16 via 10.8.0.7
```

This requires that ip_forwarding is enabled on PC A (assuming it's a Linux box, I'm sure there's a similar concept in other OSes).  I'm not sure if the "ip" command is available on Mac.

Comment: It would also require that the devices in 192.168 know how to reach 10.8.0.0/24, e.g they should have a route via 10.8.0.7 otherwise nat is required